# Don't stop the iPod music

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipod

Is there a way to not stop the iPod music when I start my app in the iPhone?

Because when my app is launched, the music stops.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what code and sound Library you are using in your application
adding MediaPlayer.framework will help you solve the issue quickly

Take a look at this post http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/